# Eclipse plug-in: how to update a view once a Job is complete

Tags: java, eclipse, view, eclipse-plugin

The run method in my Job class, does some stuff (the details are irrelevant) and outputs 2 arrays of doubles.

I want to display these arrays in a results view which I have created with a Table and 2 columns, one for each array.

How can I reference the view and display these arrays in it at the end of the run method (in the Job class)?

Even if you cannot help me with the answer, I would be happy if someone can point me in some direction because I have no idea. The only thing I could think of was event handling but I don't know very much about that either.

```
class RunnerJob extends Job {
     protected IStatus run(IProgressMonitor monitor) {
          //does some stuff
          double[] col1 = someStuff1();
          double[] col2 = someStuff2();

          //display in results view?
  }
}
```

Based on Suraj Chandran's answer, this is the code I used to reference a view's static method,

```
display.syncExec(
    new Runnable() {
       public void run(){
           try { 
PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().showView(ResultsView.ID);
           } catch (PartInitException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
             }
                 ResultsView.update(<object with values>);
             }
     });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your view class have a static method something like getInstance() that would return reference to you view object. Once you have the object you can set the arrays in it.

Comment: So do you mean by just sayin return this;?
Because I can't reference anything non-static from a static method

Comment: Ok I created a static method that will update the view instead of gettin a reference to the view but that just causes an invalid thread access exception

Comment: actually u have to do it in the UI thread...http://www.eclipse.org/swt/faq.php#uithread

Comment: yup I got that... I found it easier instead to just call a static method in the view that will then populate whatever I need to.
I have updated my question with some of the code that I used.

Answer (score 3):

Use [observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern)  (see [example](http://bquot.com/w5)):

1. Make your View implement Observer
2. Make your Job implement Observable
3. Register your View to Observable in `createPartControl()` (or in
   constructor), and don't forget to unregister it in `dispose()`.
4. Notify Observers when the Job is done.

Comment: This does sound very clean and I will update as soon as I try it out. I have accepted that answer as it worked for me and I haven't had time to try this out. But I will definitely add the feedback as soon as I can.