# What is the proper way to call complex operation from a wizard in Eclipse RCP?

Tags: java, eclipse, asynchronous, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am trying to initiate complex operation from a wizard.

It includes showing some view and then initiating of this view, which is long.

First way I was just calling view creation code from wizard's `performFinish()`

But this was not beautiful, since wizard was hanging on pressing `Finish` button. User would not see that execution began.

Other way I was trying to call Eclipse command from `performFinish()` and wrote handler to handle this command. I was thinking this will add some asynchronicity.

Unfortunately, I found no way to pass complex objects to a command. Method `org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(ExecutionEvent)` accepts `ExecutionEvent`, which allows to pass map of parameters, but values should all be of `String` type. `ExecutionEvent` is final and I am unable to add by own properties to it.

So what is the proper way to call complex operation from a wizard in Eclipse RCP?

**UPDATE**

If I am trying to use `Job`, I am getting `org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Invalid thread access`

**UPDATE 2**

The same is with `IRunnableWithProgress`.

Probably I need put view initialization into another thread...

Comment: You are probably trying to call UI elements from your Job. Eclipse runs all that UI stuff in its UI thread. If you do a long running operation in a UIElement, it will run in the UI thread, too. With that Job Framework it creates a diferent thread, so the UI Thread can continue. However you can access the UI Thread with an asychrous call `Display.asyncExec` or a synchronous one `Display.syncExec`.

Comment: Maybe this thread might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6292523/eclipse-plug-in-how-to-update-a-view-once-a-job-is-complete. The Observer pattern sounds good to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As an alternative to using a `Job` you can also get the wizard to display a progress bar at the bottom of the wizard while your code is running. To do this call

```
setNeedsProgressMonitor(true);
```

in the constructor of your `Wizard`.

In the `performFinish` use:

```
getContainer().run(true, true, new WorkClass());
```

where `WorkClass` is a class you define which implements `IRunnableWithProgress`:

```
class WorkClass implements IRunnableWithProgress
{
  @Override
  public void run(final IProgressMonitor monitor)
     throws InvocationTargetException, InterruptedException
  {
    // Your work here updating the progress monitor
  }
}
```

Using this code your wizard will remain open showing a progress bar until the work is done. Using a `Job` the wizard will close and progress will be show in the status line or a pop-up dialog.

In both cases you need to use `Display.asycnExec` or `Display.syncExec` to update the UI:

```
Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new Runnable()
  {
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
       // Work which updates the UI
    }
  });
```

Comment: I deleted my answer suggesting to use `Job` as this is the correct way to execute long running tasks _when finishing a wizard_.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a long-running or complex task to execute at the end of the wizard then it's best to just use the wizard to gather and validate information. On `performFinish()` you can then use the [Eclipse Jobs API](https://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Concurrency/jobs-api.html) to asynchronously execute the task.

```
    Job job = new Job("name") {
        @Override
        protected IStatus run(IProgressMonitor monitor) {
            // TODO Complex task
            return Status.OK_STATUS;
        }
    };
    job.schedule();
```

If you feed progress information back to the `IProgressMonitor` then the status of the job will be visible in the Eclipse Progress view.

To pass in information from the wizard you can either extend `Job` with your own class or just have the job code access fields or final variables in the wizard class.